# Chernoff bound probability: value of $n$ so that with probability $.999$ at least half of the coin flips come out heads

Tags: probability-theory, boundary-value-problem

> **Problem 3:** Consider a biased coin with probability $p = \frac{1}{3}$ of landing heads and probability $\frac{2}{3}$ of landing tails. Suppose the coin is flipped some number $n$ of times, and let $X_i$ be a random variable denoting the $i$'th flip, where $X_i = 1$ means heads, and $X_i = 0$ means tails *(i.e., $X_i$ is the indicator random variable of the $i$'th flip being heads)*. Use the Chernoff bound to determine a value for $n$ so that the probability that more than half of the coin flips come out heads is less than $0.001$.

I have tried using the formula and got $n=147$, where did I go wrong? What I have tried to do is
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{ X > \frac{n}{2} \right\}<0.001=\frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{sx}]}{e^{sn/2}}
$$

Comment: Which Chernoff bound are you using? Here are some [convenient ones](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Readings/chernoffbounds.pdf).

Comment: what is the expected answer? show us how did you get $n=147$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Using the Chernoff bound (as stated [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Readings/chernoffbounds.pdf) as (2) for reference):

> $$
> \forall\gamma\in(0,1],\qquad \mathbb{P}\!\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > (1+\gamma)np \right\} \leq e^{-\gamma^2 \frac{np}{3}}\,.\tag{$\dagger$}
> $$

We want $(1+\gamma)np = \frac{n}{2}$, and since $p=\frac{1}{3}$ this leads to setting $\gamma\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{2}$ in $(\dagger)$. Thus, we have an upper bound on the probability of 
$$ 
e^{-\gamma^2 \frac{np}{3}} = e^{-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \frac{n}{9}} = e^{-\frac{n}{36}}\,.
$$
To make sure the probability is at most $\frac{1}{1000}$, it suffices to choose $n$ such that our upper bound on the probability is less than $\frac{1}{1000}$, i.e. 
$
e^{-\frac{n}{36}} < \frac{1}{1000}
$, 
or equivalently 
$$
n >  36\ln 1000 \simeq 248.7\,.
$$ 
Therefore, choosing $\boxed{n = 249}$ is sufficient.

Comment: Also,  note that the Hoeffding bound ((1) in the link in my answer) would lead to a tighter result: here, $n> 18 \ln 1000$, so $\boxed{n=125}$ would be enough.